# PostgreSQL statistical mode value

Tags: postgresql, statistics

I am using the SQL query

```sql
    SELECT round(avg(int_value)) AS modal_value FROM t;
```

to obtain [modal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29), that, of couse, not is correct, but is a first option to show some result.

So, my question is, "**How to do the thing right?**".

---

With PostgreSQL 8.3+  we **can use [this user-defined agregate](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Mode)** to define *mode*:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION _final_mode(anyarray) RETURNS anyelement AS $f$
    SELECT a FROM unnest($1) a
    GROUP BY 1  ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC, 1
    LIMIT 1;
$f$ LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE;
CREATE AGGREGATE mode(anyelement) (
  SFUNC=array_append,  STYPE=anyarray,
  FINALFUNC=_final_mode, INITCOND='{}'
);
```

but, as an user-defined average, with big tables it can be slow (compare sum/count with buildin AVG function).  **With PostgreSQL 9+, there are no direct (buildin) function for calculate *statistical mode* value?**  Perhaps using `pg_stats`... **How to do** something like

```sql
    SELECT (most_common_vals(int_value))[1] AS modal_value FROM t;
```

The [pg_stats](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/view-pg-stats.html) VIEW can be used for this kind of task (even once, by hand)?

Comment: `pg_stat` view (as any table/view, that deal with planner statistics) contains only estimates, not the exact value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since PostgreSQL 9.4 there is a built-in aggregate function `mode`. It is used like

```
SELECT mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY some_value) AS modal_value FROM tbl;
```

Read more about ordered-set aggregate functions here:

[36.10.3. Ordered-Set Aggregates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xaggr.html)

[Built-in Ordered-Set Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE)

See other answers for dealing with older versions of Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it by groups:

```
select
    int_value * 10 / (select max(int_value) from t) g,
    min(int_value) "from",
    max(int_value) "to",
    count(*) total
from t
group by 1
order by 4 desc
```

Comment: Thanks @ClonaldoNeto, this is a good solution (!) for [scalars and measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(mathematics)),
to detect "modal intervals".

Comment: PS for reader: the first line (limit 1) is the mode; if you change 10 by 30 or by 100 you get more (and tiny) intervals; and to list intervals use "order by 1".

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT int_value, count(*)
FROM t
GROUP BY int_value
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The idea behind it - you get the count for every `int_value`, then order them (so that the biggest `count` goes first), then `LIMIT` the query to first row only, to get the `int_value` with highest count only.

Comment: Thanks!  Well, I understand that my dream of "buildin function" is only a dream.... is it? About your query, check if it is not "exactly" (not generalized for aggregation) the same algorithm than [my cited link](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Mode), at `_final_mode()` function.

Comment: @PeterKrauss Yes, the idea is the same, just applied directly, without collectiong into array and unnesting.

Answer (score 0):

At the question introductiom I cited [this link](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Mode) with a good SQL-coded solution (and  @IgorRomanchenko used the same algorithm in this answer). @ClodoaldoNeto shows a "new solution", but is for [scalars and measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(mathematics)) as I comment, not is an answer for the current question.

Pasted 2 months and ~40Views, *no new issue*...

### Conlusions

Conclusions using only informations (and evidence of the absence of further info) of this page and cited links. Summary:

1. The user-defined  aggregate `mode()` is enough, we not need a build-in (compiled) version.
2. There are no infrastructure for optimizations, a build-in do the something than the user-defined.

---

I tested the [cited SQL aggregate function](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Mode) , in contexts like

```
SELECT mode(some_value) AS modal_value FROM t;
```

And, on my tests, it was fast... So, not justify an "build-in function" (like `STATS_MODE` of Oracle), only in a "statistical package" demand context -- but if you will spend time and memory to install something I suggest [`R` language](http://www.joeconway.com/plr/).

Another implicit question, was about a statistical package "preparing" or making use of some PostgreSQL-infrastructure (like [pg_stats](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/view-pg-stats.html))... A good clue for a "canonical answer" is at the comment of @IgorRomanchenko: "`pg_stat` (...) contains only estimates, not the exact value". So, mode function can not make use of infrastructure, as I supposed.

NOTE: we must remember that, for "modal intervals", we can use another function, see  @ClodoaldoNeto's answer.

Comment: Hi @Luffydude, check your PostgreSQL version (!), and [the cited link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Mode#mode.28.29_for_Postgres_9.3_or_earlier_.28superseded_in_9.4.29) (you can copy/paste the function for old versions).

Answer (score 0):

The mode is of the most value that has occurred, so I sobreescrevi the function I found [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Mode) and I made this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _final_mode(anyarray)
  RETURNS anyelement AS
    $BODY$
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN t1.cnt <> t2.cnt THEN t1.a 
            ELSE NULL 
        END
        FROM
            (SELECT a, COUNT(*) AS cnt
             FROM unnest($1) a
             WHERE a IS NOT NULL
             GROUP BY 1 
             ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, 1
             LIMIT 1
            ) as t1, 
            (SELECT a,
             COUNT(*) AS cnt
             FROM unnest($1) a
             WHERE a IS NOT NULL
             GROUP BY 1 
             ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, 1
             LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1
            ) as t2
    $BODY$
LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE;

-- Tell Postgres how to use our aggregate
CREATE AGGREGATE mode(anyelement) (
  SFUNC=array_append, --Function to call for each row. Just builds the array
  STYPE=anyarray,
  FINALFUNC=_final_mode, --Function to call after everything has been added to array
  INITCOND='{}' --Initialize an empty array when starting
);
```

Comment: Hello Bruno. I posted above a comment to IgorRomanchenko with this same wiki link... Check if our discution cover your answer (also the agregate function I was present above as `_final_mode`). The question is not about "how to reproduce the *mode* with SQL", but "where the PostgreSQL's build-in function" that do fast this kind of operarion.